How can I change parameters of slash command?
I am using discord.py. For example, if there is a command named "/food" If user use "/food asian" There is a new parameter. The new parameter includes "korean", "japanese", "chinese" And if user use "/food european" There is a new parameter that includes "german", "french", "english" How can I change parameters of slash command?

Can you edit your question to include your code so far? What have you tried, why is it not working.

What you are trying to do is impossible. The way that slash commands are registered in discord do not allow for parameters to be changed on the go. However, we can do something a little different that allows us to do something very similar.
What the following approach does is take the user's first input and return a select menu where they can select their second response. This means that you can tie a different view to a different response (However, in the example I used the same view twice, you can of course use a different view for each response so that you can give the user more options).
Here's an example:
# --- Imports ---
import discord
import os
from discord import app_commands
from discord.ui import Select

intents = discord.Intents.default()
bot = discord.Client(intents=intents)
tree = app_commands.CommandTree(bot)

# --- Sync Commands ---
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    await tree.sync()
    print('tree synced')

# --- View used later to select the food's country or something ---
class View(discord.ui.View):
    @discord.ui.select(cls=Select, options=[discord.SelectOption(label=x, value=x) for x in ['France', 'other_country', 'other_other_country']])
    async def select_country(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, select):
        return await interaction.response.send_message(f'You selected {select.values[0]}')

# --- Command to select food ---
@tree.command()
@app_commands.choices(food=[
    app_commands.Choice(name="Choice_one", value="1"),
    app_commands.Choice(name="Choice_two", value="2")
])
async def testing_options(ctx, food: app_commands.Choice[str]):
    # Return view
    if food == "1":  # If the food selected is the first choice
        await ctx.response.send_message('Hello', view=View())
    else:  # If the food is the second choice
        await ctx.response.send_message('Hello2', view=View())  # I used the same view twice, but if you want a different select menu, use another view

This is what the output is:
When running the command:

When inputting something not there:

When you input something valid:

When you select something in the view's select menu:

Documentation used

How to add options to an argument of a slash command in discord.py?
How do i make a working slash command in discord.py
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/interactions/api.html?highlight=select#discord.ui.select

